# Python map a filesystem to a directory structure: works, ...but how?

Tags: python, reduce

I am parsing through a directory. I found [a snippet here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577879-create-a-nested-dictionary-from-oswalk/), that works well, but I cannot seem to figure out why and how their variable `dir` is updated where it is set.

What I am trying to do is leave out empty folders

```
import os

def get_directory_structure(rootdir):
    """
    Creates a nested dictionary that represents the folder structure of rootdir
    """
    dir = {}
    rootdir = rootdir.rstrip(os.sep)
    start = rootdir.rfind(os.sep) + 1
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        folders = path[start:].split(os.sep)
        subdir = dict.fromkeys(files)
        parent = reduce(dict.get, folders[:-1], dir)
        parent[folders[-1]] = subdir
    return dir
```

`dir` is being set to the same value as parent along the line:

```
        parent[folders[-1]] = subdir
```

How come?

`dir` is mutable and taken as input in the `reduce` line, but it is not set there, rather at the following line.

Any idea?

I want to be able to leave out the empty folders, and would rather find an elegant way to do it; Should I give up and skim through the dict as a second pass?

[Edit after solved] so as Hans and Adrin pointed out, reduce actually makes parent point to dir, so they are the same object, and any update to parent updates dir.

I ended up keeping the same code but renamed the vars for clarity:

`dir` -> `token_dict`
`folders` -> `path_as_list`
`subdir` -> `files_in_dir`
`parent` -> `full_dir` (and I end up returning `full_dir`)

More typing, but next time I look, I'll get to it straight away.

Comment: Perhaps in `parent = reduce(dict.get, folders[:-1], dir)`?

Comment: Since there's only one line which could be a candidate...

Comment: Well, in fact, `parent` then points to `dir` and updates it one line later.

Comment: Wow you are fast.
How does parent point to dir? I understand it is a mutable, but how is it updated there?
Or is the statement `parent = reduce(...)` defining parent in a dynamic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `dir` to the `reduce` function. Meaning, you're passing a pointer to the object to the function, and the function can change it.

Look at the implementation of the `reduce` function [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce). And note the line:

```
accum_value = function(accum_value, x)
```

At this point, `accum_value` is pointing to the same place as `initializer` which is your `dir`, and is passed to the function, which in your case is `dict.get`.

Comment: In fact, `dir` here is not a function as far as I can see, just a horribly named variable. I changed it to `dir_` and it still works.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant, you're passing `dir` to the `reduce`. Edited.

Comment: Thanks adrin, and @Hans Zauber, OK, I got it.
Thanks very much for your decryption: `parent` then points to mutable `dir`

Comment: first of all he should not use dir as name, it make some one confuse.

Answer (score 3):

Little bit of explanation about reduce with dictionary for anybody who are not much familiar with reduce:

Before we come to the snippet lets do a little bit of reduce function.

`Reduce will apply a function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of a sequence,
from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.`

Here is the syntax:

```
reduce(function, sequence[, initial]) -> value
```

If initial is present, it is placed before the items of the sequence in the calculation,
and serves as a default when the sequence is empty.

Without initial:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
15
>>>
smiliar to ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)
```

With initial:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [], 1) 
1
>>>
```

That is about list, when it comes to dictionary:

First lets check what is `dict.get()` method can do :

```
>>> d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'files'}}}
>>> dict.get(d,'a')
{'b': {'c': 'files'}}
>>>
```

So, when you put dict.get method inside reduce, this is what happens:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'b': {'c': 'files'}}}
{'b': {'c': 'files'}}
>>> reduce(dict.get, ['a','b','c'], d)
'files'
>>>
```

Which is similar to :

```
>>> dict.get(dict.get(dict.get(d,'a'),'b'),'c')
'files'
>>>
```

and when you got empty list, you will get empty dict which is the default value:

```
>>> reduce(dict.get, [], {})
{}
>>>
```

Lets come back to your snippet:

dir in your snippet != **builtin** dir() function, it is just a name bind to an empty dictionary.

```
parent = reduce(dict.get, folders[:-1], dir)
```

So, in the above line, folders[:-1] is just a list of directories. and dir is empty_dictionary.

Please let me know if it helps in anyway.

Comment: It does help, and it does well. Thanks Yopi. I am working on further manipulations of the dict, and this comes in very handy. I agree that some names in this code were very, very unfortunate and only obscured the purpose. The code itself is however very clean and smart.